# Condition is always true

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения

В общем дана задача на нахождение НОД.
Следуя данному алгоритму - всё работает, кроме одного.
Idea ругается что в `while (a != 0 || b != 0)` - Condition is always true.
При запуске код падает с ArithmeticException: / by zero, потому что даже когда `a` либо `b` доходит до 0, то всё равно выполняется цикл `while`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            while (a != 0 || b != 0) {
                if (a > b)
                    a = a % b;
                else
                    b = b % a;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
```

Вот в таком варианте - всё работает, исключений нету

```
while (true) {
            if (a != 0) {
                if (b != 0) {
                    if (a > b)
                        a = a % b;
                    else
                        b = b % a;
                } else
                    break;
            } else
                break;
        }
```

Comment: на "a != 0 && b != 0" замените

Comment: @Miron спасибо, глупая у меня оказалась ошибка, т.к. теперь понял что "Пока а не равно 0 и б не равно 0" то цикл выполняется.
А в моём случае программа перестала бы выполняться только если бы и 'a' и 'b' стали бы 0.